# Like button not working when not logged in

Tags: button, facebook-like, invisible

I am trying to put a like button on a webpage. The like button is referring to a facebook page. The facebook page is:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Passie4Flora-uw-tuin-onze-passie/122272884516200

When I am creating the like button on the developers page and I am not logged in to facebook I cannot see the button. When I log in I can see the button. I have tried several other url's which seem to work fine but I want to use the above link.

Please help.

Comment: This URL doesn't work for me, maybe that is your problem?

Comment: That is very strange, because I can click on it from multiple browsers and computers. I will check from some more locations. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your page is restricted* in any way (by age, location, restricted for alcohol related content). (And that Kyle says in his comment he can’t view the page [me neither], seems to support that this is the case.)

Since for a user that is not logged in Facebook can not know whether they meet those restrictions – the like button is not displayed in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look for that. I will inform you soon. Thanks for the input.